# if else condition not matched then move script ahed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am creating a bash script.. Where I want to check in a file if its out is 1 or 0. If the output is one we need to execute a command if not then the script should move ahed. The part of script will be like below

```
#!/bin/bash
checkifVMactive(){
  foo=$(cat /home/ubuntu/active.txt)
  if (( $foo = 0 )) then
       curl localhost/startvm.php
  else
       [now I don't know what to put here to move the script ahed]
  fi
```

can someone please help me for the same

Answer (score 1):

I made a more simple example than yours.
Mine works fine.
If active.txt contains a single 0 then I get this:

> foo is 0 .. do stuff
>  going to the bar now ;) (geek code pun)

If active.txt contains anything but a single 0 then I get this:

> going to the bar now ;) (geek code pun)

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=$(cat $PWD/active.txt)
if [ $foo = 0 ]; then
     echo foo is 0 .. do stuff
fi
echo going to the bar now \;\) \(geek code pun\)
```

I hope this helps.